# jquery and html drag and drop image upload

Tags: php, jquery

i have been using this jquery and html image upload script fine without any problems, 
the script allows a user to drag an image over to the target area and drop it, this then uploads the image and displays it.

my problem is that its now stopped working and i cant find out why (i havn't changed anything that i know of)

also its never ever worked in firefox, users cant upload by choosing file or drag and drop. so my other question is why has it stopped working and also why is it completely unresponsive in firefox, maybe its just just one line of code im using that could be changed, i dont really know but im hoping someone might have some ideas, thanks.

index.php:

```
 <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <div id="devcontainer">
            <!-- development area -->
            <script src="droparea.js"></script>
            <style>
                .droparea {
                    position:relative;
                    text-align: center;
                    width:180px;
                    height:190px;
                    margin-left:-5px;
                }
                .multiple {
                    position:relative;
                    height: 20px;
                }
                .droparea div, .droparea input, .multiple div, .multiple input {
                    position: absolute;
                    top:0;
                    width: 180px;
                    height: 190px;
                }
                .droparea input, .multiple input {
                    cursor: pointer; 
                    opacity: 0; 
                }

                .droparea {
                    border: none;
                    color:#666;
                    background-color:#FFFFFF;
                    font-size: 0px;
    font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    width:180px;
                    height:190px;
                }

                .instructions {
                    padding-top:90px;
                    padding-left:0px;
                    color:#666;
                    text-align:center;
                    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    height:180px;
    width:190px;

                }


                .droparea .progress, .multiple .progress {
                    position:absolute;
                    bottom: 0;
                    width: 180px;
                    height: 190px;
                    color: #fff;
                    background-image:url(../../assets/img/effects/wait.jpg)


                }
                .multiple .progress {
                    width: 180px;
                    height: 190px;
                }


                #areas { float: left; width: 180px; height:190px;}
                div.spot {
                    float: left;
                    margin-left: -4px;
                    margin-top:-4px;

                }
                .thumb {
                    float: left;
                    margin:0 0px 0px 0;
                    width: 180px;
                    min-height: 190px;
                }
                .desc {
                    float:left;
                    width: 180px;
                    height:190px;
                }
                .signature a { color:#555; text-decoration:none; }
                .signature img { margin-right:0px; vertical-align: middle; }
                input[type=text], textarea {
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    padding: 0px;
                    width: 180px;
                    height: 190px;
                    border: 1px solid #bbb;
                }
                textarea {
                    height: 58px;
                }
                input[type=submit] {
                    float: right;
                    margin-right: 20px;
                    padding: 5px 25px;
                    color: #111;
                    border: 1px solid #666;
                    background: #888;
                    width:180px;
                    height:190px;
                }
                h3 { clear: both; padding:5px 0; }
                #sampleform { width: 180px; width:190px; }
            </style>

            <div id="areas">

                <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile" data-post="upload.php" data-width="180" data-height="190" data-crop="true"/>


                <form id="sampleform" action="post.php" method="post">

                </form>
                <script>
                    $('#sampleform').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:$(this).attr('action'),
                            type:'post',
                            data:$(this).serialize(),
                            dataType:'json',
                            success:function(r){
                                $('#form-result').append(
                                '<div><b>Title: </b>'+r.title+'</div>'
                                ,'<div><b>Description: </b>'+r.description+'</div>'
                                ,'<div><b>Image/File: </b>'
                                  +'<a href="'+ r.url +'" target="_blank">'+ r.url +'</a>'
                                  +'</div>'
                                );
                            }
                        });
                });
                </script>
            </div>

            <script>
            // Calling jQuery "droparea" plugin
            $('.droparea').droparea({
                'init' : function(result){
                    //console.log('custom init',result);
                },
                'start' : function(area){
                    area.find('.error').remove(); 
                },
                'error' : function(result, input, area){
                    $('<div class="error">').html(result.error).prependTo(area); 
                    return 0;
                    //console.log('custom error',result.error);
                },
                'complete' : function(result, file, input, area){
                    if((/image/i).test(file.type)){
                        area.find('img').remove();
                        //area.data('value',result.filename);
                        area.append($('<img>',{'src': result.path + result.filename + '?' + Math.random()}));
                    } 
                    //console.log('custom complete',result);
                }
            });
            </script>

            <!-- /development area -->
        </div>
```

post.php:

```
<?php

// LOG
$log = '=== ' . @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ===============================' . "\n"
        . 'FILES:' . print_r($_FILES, 1) . "\n"
        . 'POST:' . print_r($_POST, 1) . "\n";
$fp = fopen('post-log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $log);
fclose($fp);


// Result object
$r = new stdClass();
// Result content type
header('content-type: application/json');


$data = $_POST['thumbnail'];
unset($_POST['thumbnail']);

if($data){


  // Uploading folder
    $folder = '../'. '../'. 'data/'. 'photos/'. $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        mkdir($folder);

    // If specifics folder 
    $folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        mkdir($folder);


    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . sha1(@microtime() . '-' . $_POST['_default']) . '.jpg';


    $data = split(',', $data);
    file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($data[1]));

}
die(json_encode(array_merge(array('url' => $filename), $_POST)));

?>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
session_start()
?>
<?


// LOG
$log = '=== ' . @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ===============================' . "\n"
        . 'FILES:' . print_r($_FILES, 1) . "\n"
        . 'POST:' . print_r($_POST, 1) . "\n";
$fp = fopen('upload-log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $log);
fclose($fp);


// Result object
$r = new stdClass();
// Result content type
header('content-type: application/json');


// Maximum file size
$maxsize = 10; //Mb
// File size control
if ($_FILES['xfile']['size'] > ($maxsize * 1048576)) {
    $r->error = "Max file size: $maxsize Kb";
}


// Uploading folder
$folder = '../'. '../'. 'data/'. 'photos/'. $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);

// If specifics folder 
$folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);

// PASS USER_ID HERE
$folder2 = '../'. '../'. 'data/'. 'photos/'. $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';
if (!is_dir($folder2))
    mkdir($folder2);

// New directory with 'files/USER_SESSION_ID/'
$folder = $newDir . $folder2;


// If the file is an image
if (preg_match('/image/i', $_FILES['xfile']['type'])) {

    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . '_default.jpg';
} else {

    $tld = split(',', $_FILES['xfile']['name']);
    $tld = $tld[count($tld) - 1];
    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . sha1(@microtime() . '-' . $_FILES['xfile']['name']) . $tld;
}


// Supporting image file types
$types = Array('image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg');
// File type control
if (in_array($_FILES['xfile']['type'], $types)) {
    // Create an unique file name    
    // Uploaded file source
    $source = file_get_contents($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"]);
    // Image resize
    imageresize($source, $filename, $_POST['width'], $_POST['height'], $_POST['crop'], $_POST['quality']);
} else
// If the file is not an image
if (in_array($_FILES['xfile']['type'], $types)) 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"], $filename);



// File path
$path = str_replace('upload.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

// Result data
$r->filename = $filename;
$r->path = $path;
$r->img = '<img src="' . $path . $filename . '" alt="image" />';

// Return to JSON
echo json_encode($r);

// Image resize function with php + gd2 lib
function imageresize($source, $destination, $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false, $quality = 100) {
    $quality = $quality ? $quality : 100;
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($source);
    if ($image) {
        // Get dimensions
        $w = imagesx($image);
        $h = imagesy($image);
        if (($width && $w > $width) || ($height && $h > $height)) {
            $ratio = $w / $h;
            if (($ratio >= 1 || $height == 0) && $width && !$crop) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } elseif ($crop && $ratio <= ($width / $height)) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } else {
                $new_width = $height * $ratio;
                $new_height = $height;
            }
        } else {
            $new_width = $w;
            $new_height = $h;
        }
        $x_mid = $new_width * .5;  //horizontal middle
        $y_mid = $new_height * .5; //vertical middle
        // Resample
        error_log('height: ' . $new_height . ' - width: ' . $new_width);
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height));
        imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
        // Crop
        if ($crop) {
            $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($width ? $width : $new_width, $height ? $height : $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($crop, $new, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($width * .5)), 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
            //($y_mid - ($height * .5))
        }
        // Output
        // Enable interlancing [for progressive JPEG]
        imageinterlace($crop ? $crop : $new, true);

        $dext = strtolower(pathinfo($destination, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($dext == '') {
            $dext = $ext;
            $destination .= '.' . $ext;
        }
        switch ($dext) {
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'jpg':
            $jpgQuality = ($quality - 100) / 11.111111;
            $jpegQuality = ($quality - 100) / 11.111111;
                imagejpeg($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $quality);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $pngQuality = ($quality - 100) / 11.111111;
                $pngQuality = round(abs($pngQuality));
                imagepng($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $pngQuality);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                imagegif($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination);
                break;
        }
        @imagedestroy($image);
        @imagedestroy($new);
        @imagedestroy($crop);
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a more modern version of jQuery? :)

Comment: im affraid im really new to jquery and so how would i do this please?

Comment: See my answer - If it solves your problem or helps you solve it, please upvote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more modern version of jQuery. You don't have to go all the way to 1.9, but you should at least try to bump yourself up to 1.7.2. I recommend that you try to get up to 1.8.2, but 1.7.2 should be sufficient. I don't even think 1.5.2 supported drag and drop, but I could be mistaken.

Change your second line to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I forgot that you will also need to reference jQuery UI. Check out the [Draggable API Reference](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) from jQuery, and also this [jQuery Draggable Tutorial](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/).

Comment: thanks, i tried 1.7.2 and 1.8.2 those don't affect anything either, it still won't work :/